# Java: JMenuItem not working with ActionMap/AbstractAction

Tags: java, swing, action, jmenu

Generic code...

For some reason my `JMenuItem` is not performing actions.

I made a frame, a `JMenuBar` and a `JMenuItem`, everything is where it should be. I can click the `JMenuItem` just fine, it highlights and closes the menu properly but no action is performed.

I added a key to the `ActionMap` with the `JMenuItem`s name. I also added a key to the Input map with the exact same name and it fires fine.

```
    'menuitem'.setActionMap(getActionMap());
    System.out.println('menuitemname'.getActionMap().size());
    System.out.println('menuitemname'.getActionCommand());
```

returns 1 and the correct action key, respectively. Clicking the menu item does nothing. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The ActionMap/InputMap are used for Key Bindings, not for mouse clicks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `setAction()` method (and maybe `setActionCommand()` as well).

Comment: No, setActionCommand will set what is returned with getActionCommand (obviously). If you look at the code provided, getActionCommand returns the correct action key.  

Am I to understand that setActionCommand does nothing? I assumed that setActionCommand would make it so that pushing the menu item would call the corresponding action for its action map...

Comment: @kleopatra: `setActionCommand()` is useful when you have your own custom `ActionListener` which is responsible for handling `ActionEvent`s. In that case one can use `setActionCommand()` and delegate the appropriate implementation of `actionPerformed()` to the object set for the action in the `ActionMap` of the component (for instance). Similarly it is useful if you want to debug code: this way you can identify your action events by their command.

Comment: if you want an actionCommand for whatever reasons, set its value on the Action, not on the button. And don't use ActionListener, ever, always go for the highest abstraction available